# VPS - Maintenance Efforts

Tags: ubuntu, vps, maintenance

I'm contemplating about moving my current website to a VPS - Plan instead of a shared hosting which I'm on now to make the deployment process of updates a lot easier (the shared hosting environment i'm on now doesn't allow SSH access).

However, I want to be able to spend as less time as possible not on my core business, so I was wondering how many hours a week VPS maintenance costs an which tasks are involved.

I'm planning on using a Ubuntu server + free control panel like Vesta CP. I need to be able to send mail and receive customer support emails as wel.

Does the control panel aid in keeping all services updates (php / mysql/ mail daemon etc). Do note, i have experience with ubuntu and general server management and linux stuff, but I can't make a assessment about how much effort is invovled.

thanks for your input and experiences :)

Comment: There are shared/managed hosts that offer SSH access. I'd suggest you take that route instead.

Answer (score 0):

For a small scale site Ubuntu can be kept a very low maintenance by enabling automatic updates. This puts my vps in this class at requiring one to two hours per year. If you have a higher traffic site than detecting database issues, network, disk space and failed upgrades are likely to consume more time which is setup specific.

The other issue with your own vps is knowing there is a problem, shared hosting when done well is monitored and admins address the issues. To have the same you will need to create monitors which can be an additional cost monthly and setup time

Answer (score -1):

Nice to hear that you are moving to a VPS which will be more powerful, flexible and gives complete freedom to you.

If you want to spend as less time as possible then it will be good to go with Vesta CP, that will handle all the configuration itself. And GUI if are not much into ssh. and it save a lot of pain of installing, config, managing mail server.

don't know about the auto update of php and other software by Vesta, but you can always update them manually using 'apt-get install program_name' command, It is recommended to always keep your programs and O.S updated and Upgraded for security reasons. 3 hours/week should be enough to update everything.

and as a system admin you have to install some anti malware or manually check all files for malicious files/users (Vesta comes with ClamAV anti-malware, auto installed on VPS with 7GB or more RAM). and keep eye on the server performances, error logs, hacking attempts. at minimum at would be 1hour/day = 7hours/week

so total minimum time cost = 10 hours/week

Hope this will help.
Good Luck for your website